# Can't createChatThread() with Preview 4 azure-sdk-for-js

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-communication-services

The example code snippet @ https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/%40azure/communication-identity_1.0.0-beta.4/sdk/communication/communication-chat does NOT compile.

```
import { ChatClient, ChatThreadClient } from '@azure/communication-chat';
import { AzureCommunicationTokenCredential } from '@azure/communication-common';

let createChatThreadRequest =
{
    topic: 'Preparation for London conference',
    participants:
        [
            {
                user: { communicationUserId: '<USER_ID_FOR_JACK>' },
                displayName: 'Jack'
            },
            {
                user: { communicationUserId: '<USER_ID_FOR_GEETA>' },
                displayName: 'Geeta'
            }
        ]
};

let createChatThreadResponse = await chatClient.createChatThread(createChatThreadRequest);
let threadId = createChatThreadResponse.chatThread.id;
```

my package.json:

```
"@azure/communication-identity": "1.0.0-beta.4",
"@azure/communication-calling": "1.0.0-beta.6",
"@azure/communication-chat": "1.0.0-beta.4",
"@azure/communication-common": "1.0.0-beta.5",
"@azure/communication-signaling": "1.0.0-beta.2",
```

Latest attempt:

```
createChatThreadRequest:
{
    "topic": "Ghost Frog",
    "participants": [
        {
            "user": {
                "communicationUserId": "ey...Ug"
            },
            "displayName": "frog"
        }
    ]
}
```

POST error 400
https://########.communication.azure.com/chat/threads?api-version=2020-11-01-preview3

RestError: {"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"One or more validation errors occurred.","details":[{"message":"The value provided for Id is invalid.","target":"Participants[0].Id"}]}}

The error message is looking for a property named 'Id'. The spec does NOT require an Id. Arg.

Answer (score 0):

sorry you are running into issues and thank you for reaching out!

Someone on our team has tested out your code snippet and SDK versions and it compiled. Can you specify the error codes you are seeing? It will help us understand the issue better. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for addressing this so quickly. I'm embarrassed to admit, a reboot solved my problem. I think I might have some issues with my solution configuration. Regardless, this code definitely compiles now. I'll delete this question after you've had a chance to read my comment.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out :) Let us know if you run into any other issues!

Comment: I'm still dead in the water:( Anyone aware of any working sample code using the latest versions of the javascript sdk's? This code compiles but I'm using it wrong or the api is not working.

Answer (score 0):

given you are using version `1.0.0-beta.4` I can verify the code snippet you have is correct.

In the latest release of the JS SDK `1.0.0-beta.5` the `user` property was in fact renamed to `id`, however previous versions should still work as expected.

Can you verify if the latest version works for you? The error you are seeing can also occur if an invalid `communicationUserId` is provided.

Given your current version and code, if the issue is persisting we would like to investigate.

We try to keep these docs up to date during public preview but if you run into issues please let us know:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/communication/communication-chat

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/chat/get-started?pivots=programming-language-javascript